# Destroy QWidget returned from Plugin in Qt

Tags: qt, plugins, qt4, qmainwindow

My app loads a plugin which creates a window (`QWidget`), but I can not destroy it when I exit from `QMainWindow`, obviously because widget returned from plugin is not a child of `QMainWindow`. The issue is that if I make that window to be a child of mainwindow, I get a window on another window. But I need them both to be separated. I did them separated (but main window has no control over window from plugin), in my case I do not know how to close window from plugin when app quits. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete it. If you don't assign it a parent, no other widget has ownership. So you should simply be able to destroy it yourself on exit.